# getting filenname in a combox PHP

Tags: php, glob, file-handling

i want to get the filenames inside a folder in a combo box.
here is my code

```
$directory = "keys/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
 echo "yes";
//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
echo $image;
}
```

it is supposed to show the filenames but it is not showing any filenames.

Comment: What is the output of `GLOB_ERR`?

Comment: try print_r(glob("*.jpg"));

Comment: @PraveenKumar its output is 4

Comment: @Arunu but it will not look into specfic directory

Comment: $a = glob('/keys/*.jpg');
print_r($a);

Comment: Could you define "not running"? is the word "yes" getting printed? is this within an `if` statement?

Comment: @Arunu it shows empty array

Comment: @RyanNaddy yes "yes" is printed

Comment: is your directory path correct?

Comment: @RyanNaddy yes it is correct

Comment: Are you sure there are jpg images in the directory?

Comment: @RyanNaddy yes it is correct

Comment: @RyanNaddy glob_err shows 4

Comment: `var_dump($images);` - Also enable error reporting and logging to the highest level. Trace the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this it should help you debug your code. You should do debugging in the future.

```
/*
 * glob() a pattern inside a directory
 */
$directory = "keys/";
$pattern   = "*.jpg";

if (!is_dir($directory)) {
    throw new Exception('Directory was not found!');
}

$images = glob($directory . $pattern);

if (FALSE === $images) {
    throw new Exception('Glob returned an error.');
}

if (!$images) {
    throw new Exception('No files returned by Glob. That was not expected.');
}

// print each file name
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image;
}
```

Comment: @user1765876 just curious to know.what was the problem?

Comment: Yeah, what was the problem?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I just run the code like this.. it was executed successfully